# How to add tags to an S3 Bucket without deleting the existing tags using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using this function:
`aws s3api put-bucket-tagging --bucket $bucket --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=ss,Value=mm}]`

It is deleting the existing tags and I can see only one tag.

Answer (score 8):

That is how the API works, yes - that is how PUT APIs work in general, POST APIs may append a new tag or add a new property, etc. but PUT APIs overwrite.

To get this to work despite that you need to retrieve all tags, combine them with the new tags, and then put all tags at once. You can do that easily using e.g. `jq`:

```
# assuming there are already tags otherwise the get-bucket-tagging fails
data=$(aws s3api get-bucket-tagging --bucket $bucket | jq '.TagSet += [{"Key":"tag2", "Value": "value2"}]')
aws s3api put-bucket-tagging --bucket $bucket --tagging "$data"
aws s3api get-bucket-tagging --bucket $bucket # should print the merged tags
```

Comment: I would put quotations around "$data" in the put tag call, otherwise it will try to parse the data as CLI options.

Comment: This will not work if the resource you are trying to tag has a special "aws:" tag (created by Cloudformation).  You can only do it via the AWS Console (I found found a way with boto3)